# SumForumla: Two sumformula functions copied to two different cells in a "total" sheet

Tags: vba, excel

The macro below creates `i` number of new sheets and copies the total in E13 to a "total" sheet in cell F6.  We also need to take the total from "Resource Calculator" cell E14 and copy that to the "total" sheet cell F7.  Looking for suggestions for a good way to do this.  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Mac()
    Sheets("total").Visible = True

    Dim i As Integer, SumFormula As String
    For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("A15").Value
        Sheets("Resource Estimator").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Batch " & i

        If i = 1 Then
            SumFormula = "=SUM('" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!E13" 'begin sum formula
        Else
            SumFormula = SumFormula & ",'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!E13" 'iterate sum formula
        End If
    Next i

    SumFormula = SumFormula & ")" 'end sum formula
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total").Range("F6").Formula = SumFormula 'write sum formula to cell F6
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot going on in the code, should you be looping through every sheet? Why it a macro necessary? Seems like to me you are just taking the contents of cell E13 and putting into a value. Use option explicit on the top of the code and it will help, What is wrong with the code? Where is it breaking?

Comment: I have a series of check boxes on "Resource Estimator."  The user clicks the boxes that apply and based off the selection, two totals are generated.  Often there are cases where multiple check boxes sheets are required for a project.  The code above allows the user to generate a certain number of these check box sheets determined by what is entered in "A15."  Then each sheet created will have totals in the corresponding "E13"s and "E14"s.  Then we would like to have a "total" sheet that sums all of the generated E13s and E14s in cells F6 and F7 of the "total" sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd exploit *3D formulas* as follows:

```
For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("A15").Value
    Sheets("Resource Estimator").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Batch " & i
Next i

With Sheets("total")
    .Visible = True
    .Range("F6").Formula = "=sum('Batch 1:Batch " & i - 1 & "'!E13)"
    .Range("F7") = Sheets("Resource Estimator").Range("E14")
End With
```

BTW, watch for possible sheet name misspelling: your narrative tells about "Resource Calculator" but in your code you wrote "Resource Estimator". I assumed they are the same sheet and "Resource Estimator" as its name

Comment: ++ never knew they were called *3D formulas*...nice

Comment: @CallumDA, well at least I always find them googling like that!